# ssh passwordless login fails between Linux and Solaris

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris

I am trying to setup ssh keys for passwordless login from user1@host1 to user2@host2

Home directory (cd ~) for user1 is "/home/user1"
Home directory (cd ~) for user2 is "/opt/user2"

Below are the folders(700) & file(600) permissions on user2@host2 as you can see below.

```
user2@host2:~$ ls -ltrd /opt/user2
drwx------  11 user2   oinstall      59 Oct 16 05:30 /opt/user2
user2@host2:~$ ls -ltrd /opt/user2/.ssh
drwx------   2 user2   oinstall       5 Oct 14 23:49 /opt/user2/.ssh

user2@host2:~/.ssh$ ls -ltr /opt/user2/.ssh/*
-rw-------   1 user2   oinstall    6425 Oct 14 21:55 /opt/user2/.ssh/known_hosts
-rw-------   1 user2   oinstall     784 Oct 14 21:55 /opt/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The authorized_keys is nothing but id_rsa.pub taken from host1 server using scp

The id_rsa.pub entry is also made in /opt/user2/.ssh/known_hosts and verified to be correct(using cat -ev ).

Below is the Operating System details of host1 & host2

```
[user1@host1 test]$ uname -a
Linux host1 3.10.0-693.1.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 3 08:15:31 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
user2@host2:~/.ssh$ uname -a
SunOS host2 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v
```

While everything seems correct I am sharing the below failing ssh debug from user1@host1 to user2@host2

Kindly let me know why the ssh is failing and how could i fix the problem ?

```
[user1@host1 test]$ ssh -vvv user2@host2
OpenSSH_6.7p1 (CentrifyDC build 5.2.3-425) , OpenSSL 0.9.8zf-fips 19 Mar 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user1/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config line 49: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host2 [10.61.240.45] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_2.4
debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_2.4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "host2" from file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:258
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: gss-group1-sha1-toWM5Slw5Ew8Mqkay+al2g==,gss-group1-sha1-A/vxljAEU54gt9a48EiANQ==,gss-group1-sha1-bontcUwnM6aGfWCP21alxQ==,gss-group1-sha1-eipGX3TCiQSrx573bT1o1Q==,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: de-DE,en-US,es-ES,fr-FR,it-IT,ja-JP,ko-KR,pt-BR,zh-CN,zh-TW,i-default
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha2-256
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha2-256
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4095/8192
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 36:4f:63:08:26:e3:75:36:7f:1e:23:35:d4:bf:e9:ae
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "host2" from file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:258
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.61.240.45" from file "/home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:120
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'host2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts:258
debug2: bits set: 4126/8192
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa (0xadd950),
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug3: input_userauth_banner

This system is for the use by authorized users only. All data contained
on all systems is owned by the company and may be monitored, intercepted,
recorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any
manner, by authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)
have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy. Unauthorized or improper
use of this system may result in administrative, disciplinary action, civil
and criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or
unauthorized, constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,
recording, reading, copying, or capturing and disclosure.

IF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.

##################################################################
# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
# *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
# ***    password when logging in                            *** #
##################################################################

debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug1: Miscellaneous failure
No credentials cache found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 48:dc:25:1b:c8:51:e4:88:a3:82:48:2b:6c:18:72:f1
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 48:dc:25:1b:c8:51:e4:88:a3:82:48:2b:6c:18:72:f1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

Comment: Please change the permission of files inside host2/.ssh folder to 644 and check. have you copied the user1 public key to user2 authorized_keys file.?

Comment: how is Active directory mixing with ssh private's keys ? also as mention `authorized_keys` should be 644.

Comment: @Archemar `authorized_keys` should be 0600.  It's `known_hosts` that can (but doesn't have to) be 0644.  Reference: `man 8 sshd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your sure your server accepts public key authentication?

This would make me thinking it might be disabled:

> ```
> ##################################################################
> # *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #
> # *** Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #
> # ***    password when logging in                            *** #
> ##################################################################
> ```

Check the configuration on your server.

```
# grep ^RSAAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RSAAuthentication yes
```